# Javascript setter function with prototyping

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter, setter

I am learning Javascript. When I try to use setters with prototyping I am getting an error

> TypeError: cir1.radiusToCircle is not a function

```
var Circle = function(radius){
    this._radius = radius;
}

//prototype

Circle.prototype ={
    set radiusToCircle(rad) { this._radius = rad; },
    get radiusFromCircle() { return this._radius;},

    get area() { return (Math.PI * (this._radius * this._radius));}
};

var cir1 = new Circle(5);

cir1.radiusToCircle(14);
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cir1.radiusToCircle = 14;`.

Comment: @Tushar My bad, can you post it as an answer with some explanation.

Comment: Check examplses on MDN [Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Comment: @Andrew The set syntax works in object literals. Thus the logical place to put it is in the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a setter you need to set the property directly, not pass it through like a function argument. [Setter MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

```
cir1.radiusToCircle = 14;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing may work, but I don't know the set/get commands you are using and whether or not overloading the function is a good idea.

From the docs, it looks like the set/get will bind a callback that will run some unrelated code when you assign the member variable directly.  If that's what you are trying to do, you don't need a prototype function.

```
var Circle = function(radius){
    this._radius = radius;
}

Circle.prototype.getRadiusToCircle = function() {
    return this._radius;
}

Circle.prototype.setRadiusToCircle = function(rad) {
    this._radius = rad;
}

Circle.prototype.overloadRadiusToCircle = function(rad) {
    if(rad != null) {
        this._radius = rad;
    } else {
        return rad;
    }
}

Circle.prototype.area = function() {
    return (Math.PI * (this._radius * this._radius));
}
```

For example

```
var Circle = function(radius){
    this._radius = radius;
    this._area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
}

Circle.prototype = {
    set _radius(radius) {
        this._area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    }   
}

Circle.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return _area;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have both a property and a setter with the same name. You're making it way more complicated. The OP's code is 100% correct

Comment: kindly refer to the other answer that has a link to the documentation

Comment: You cannot use `set` inside a constructor like that. It only works in object literals thus must be added in the prototype declaration like what the OP is doing.

Comment: kindly refer to the OP's question. His code is 100% correct

Comment: ok, I moved the set command to the prototype - never used set before.  The OP is correct, but doesn't need to use the set command, which does nothing in the question.  The set command is for binding a callback to a property change.